# How do I use non-ascii characters in a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, utf-8, character-encoding

This code fills an array which is used as sorting instruction for an alphabetical list. $stringX contains the alphabet and additional characters, which are supposed to be grouped under the same heading in the alphabetical list.

In this example, the instruction is that a list item starting with Ǩ is supposed to be treated like starting with a regular K. To work with the rest of the code, the string is parsed into an array structure:

```
$stringX = "A B C D E F G H I J KǨ L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z";
$result = explode(' ', $stringX);
$settingsArray = array();

foreach ($result as $value) {
   echo "Current set: " . $value . "<br>";
   $firstInGroup = $value[0];
   $allGroupMembers = $value;
   $memberArray = str_split($allGroupMembers);
   echo "Group header: " . $firstInGroup . "<br>";
   echo "All in group: " . $allGroupMembers . "<br>";
   echo "Member array: ";
   var_dump($memberArray);
   echo "<br>";
   $settingsArray[$firstInGroup] = $memberArray;
}

$sorterSettings = $settingsArray;
```

My problem is that this apparently only works for ascii charakters. In this example, the result turns out to be:

```
Current value: KǨ
Group header: K
All in group: KǨ
Member array: array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "K" [1]=> string(1) "�" [2]=> string(1) "�" }
```

As the two character string $allGroupMembers is written into three array fields, I suspect there is a problem with the character.

I am aware that UTF-8 can cause difficulties in PHP, but I am unsure about the best solution to this. A suggestion on **how to write each character of KǨ in one array field each, preserving the special character** would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: PHP 5 and UTF-8 don't play very well together, but it is possible. You want something like Unicode Normalization C. This will group your characters and accents properly and use the least amount of space. From that, you can usually convert to UTF-8 and work with that. You can start with the Normalizer class if you're using PHP 5.3 or later.

Comment: Take a look at the comment on this page, the one with 20 upvotes, it should help you out.

Comment: This is the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php

Answer (score 0):

The most of PHP functions works with bytes, not with characters (except mb_* functions and preg_ with u modifier). For ascii strings it is Ok. 1 byte = 1 symbol. For utf-8 string this won't work.

So [`str_split`](http://php.net/str_split) works with bytes. And it's better to replace it with something more appropriable. For example you could take this [mb_str_split](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-split.php#117112) implementation. Or, just use

```
$memberArray = preg_split("//u", $allGroupMembers, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

P.S. [Explode](http://php.net/explode) is "dangerous" either. For this string it works as expected, because white space byte not used in other characters. But it could fail with other delimiter symbol.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that str_split only deals with single bytes, and your special k is encoded with 2 bytes (utf8 is a variable-length encoding, a-Z are encoded with a single byte, perfect for str_split, but your special k is 2 bytes), use a function that understands utf8 to split this.. like mb_split

```
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
$memberArray =mb_split('/./',$allGroupMembers);
```

Comment: You cannot split characters with `mb_split` without delimiter.